# Adding new form fields dynamically in ngView - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I use routing to load different templates into a ngView. One of the templates has a simple controller which contains an array of contacts. What I'm trying to do here is as simple as by clicking a link (ngclick) call a function and add a new object into the array which I expect will be reflected in my UI.

It's something like this:

```
$scope.contacts = [{name='', email=''}];

<li ng-repeat="con in contacts">
  <input type="text" ng-model="con.name"/>
  <input type="email" ng-model="con.email"/> 
</li>
<li>
  <a href ng-click="addContact()">add</a>
</li>

$scope.addContact = function() {
  $scope.contacts.push( {name='', email=''} ); //-- i can use either $scope or this to reference the array and works.
}
```

So, the UI renders well with the initial value, the addContact function is invoked on click and I see the value is pushed (length = 2) but then the function ends the array seems to be reset to one element (lenght = 1) after angularjs evaluation.

I'm not sure if this is occurring because I use ngView. I mean, I reviewed this example (http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/docs/api/ng.directive:ngController) and I don't see much differences of what I'm trying to do here, the diff is that I use routing with ngView.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdDph/

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: This should work.  Can you provide a [fiddle](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/) showing your problem?

Comment: Is the controller you've made $scope.contacts in being called again? That would blank it out. To just the initial value of `[{name='', email=''}];`

Comment: Mark: the fiddle will be as similar as the example in the url I provided above the only diff is that I'm using a template. Not sure how to make the routing to work on jsfiddle.

Mathew: I guess angularjs for some reason rebinds like I had called to load the template and blanks out the array as soon as the call leaves the function addContact(). So, my question is, do I need to tell angularjs not to do it or bind manually after ng-click?

Comment: @MathewBerg : Any comments on this?

Comment: @MarkRajcok : Any comments on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Fiddle, you are resetting the array length to 1 in the ng-show:

```
<span ng-hide="contacts.length = 1">
```

Do this and it will work:

```
<span ng-hide="contacts.length == 1">
```

Comment: Btw, <span ng-hide="contacts"> will work too since the {{expression}} will return true when they have objects within the collection.

Answer (score 0):

`{name='', email=''}` is wrong syntax btw, it should be `{name:'', email:''}`

Comment: you are right. My mistake when I wrote the code snippet. My implementation contains the correct definition of json. Any suggestion of how to solve the initial issue?

Comment: Mark found the problem as it appears ;)